# Android Httprequest is not working

Tags: android, httprequest

I am new In android , here i wanted to request a webpage and get the response. I have written this code from a tutorial , though i have written exactly same and i have given the permission in manifest file for internet access , its not working or not returning anything . here is the main activity which call the the named MainActivity.java
    package com.example.limon.myapplication;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    WebResult web = new WebResult();
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = web.getResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tv.setText(result);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
>

and this is the another class which return the response

```
package com.example.limon.myapplication;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Limon on 3/11/2015.
 */
public class WebResult {

public String getResult() throws  Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;

    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.mybringback.com");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while( (l = in.readLine()) != null ){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;
    }
    finally {
        if(in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No this does not work. That is from a very old tutorial i think. Nowadays you have to put network code in an AsyncTask or thread. You will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`now. See in the Logcat. Learn to look in the LogCat to discover errors and exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add internet permission into android manifest ? 
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

All http request can`t be used in main thread.
Read about: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml to allow all HTTP requests:

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

go to Your Project and Open `AndroidManifest.xml` and include  code like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

that will Allow to interact with Internet